# Saving a nested json value to a variable in python

Tags: python, json, api

I am trying to save a json value retrieved by an API GET to a variable so that I can POST it later into an API call. Here is what I have so far

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json
import sys
import objectpath

auth = HTTPBasicAuth("Username", "PAssword")
departmentname = "IT" #sys.argv[1]
url = "http://url.com".format( departmentname ) 
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

response = requests.request(
    "GET",
    url,
    headers=headers,
    auth=auth,
)
r = json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": "))
#print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")))
response.json()
```

I then get the response:

```
{
    "departments": [
        {
            "created_at": "2022-06-01T17:15:32Z",
            "custom_fields": {},
            "description": "IT Service Team",
            "domains": [],
            "head_user_id": #####,
            "id": ######,
            "name": "IT",
            "prime_user_id": null,
            "updated_at": "2022-06-07T16:35:25Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried `print(response['departments'][0][id'][0])` but I get an error that says string indices must be be integers.
I also tried using a for loop but get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by adding an additional json.loads:

```r
    d = json.loads(r)
    id = d['departments'][0]['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
r = json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": "))

print(r['departments'][0]['id'][0])
```

Comment: Still get the same error. Also you missed a ' in your code.

Comment: do this : ```print(type(r))``` and ```print(type(r['departments'][0]))```and tell me what you got

Comment: string indices must be integers
  File "C:\Users\AMT-659\Desktop\Untitled-3.py", line 35, in <module>
    print(type(r['departments'][0]) <class 'str'>

Comment: based on the json data you indicated on your question, ```r['departments'][0]``` should be dictionary not str, you are sure it's the data you are working with ?

Comment: I mean the API call is supposed to return the results in JSON format, right? Also shouldn't the `json.dump` and `json.loads` put it in dictionary type?

Comment: yes, but this dictionary can contain list of nested dictionaries and so on. what you get when you do ```response.json()``` ?

Comment: copy the raw json responses ```response.json()```(without processing it with json.dumps and json.loads) and paste it in your question so i can understand what is going on

Comment: `response.json()` doesn't do anything.

Comment: do ```import ast ast.literal_eval(response.text)```

Comment: Is that one line or separate? Either way, doesn't work `malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.Name object at 0x00000293BF390F70>`

Comment: what a raw response.text ```print(response.text)``` look like ?

Comment: `{"departments":[{"description":"IT Service Team","custom_fields":{},"id":20000176924,"name":"IT","created_at":"2022-06-01T17:15:32Z","updated_at":"2022-06-07T16:35:25Z","prime_user_id":null,"head_user_id":20000829309,"domains":[]}]}`

Comment: ok, now do : ```print(eval(response.text))``` and ```print(type(eval(response.text)))``` and tell me what you get

Comment: `name 'null' is not defined` on `print(eval(response.text))`

Comment: When adding single quotes around it, I get `{"departments":[{"description":"IT Service Team","custom_fields":{},"id":20000176924,"name":"IT","created_at":"2022-06-01T17:15:32Z","updated_at":"2022-06-07T16:35:25Z","prime_user_id":null,"head_user_id":20000829309,"domains":[]}]}
{"departments":[{"description":"IT Service Team","custom_fields":{},"id":20000176924,"name":"IT","created_at":"2022-06-01T17:15:32Z","updated_at":"2022-06-07T16:35:25Z","prime_user_id":null,"head_user_id":20000829309,"domains":[]}]}
<class 'str'>`